# Problems with installing torchTT

Tags: gcc, pip, pytorch, clang

I am trying to install torchTT in my computer using the command

```
std=c++17 pip install git+https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT
```

but I found the following error message:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT
  Cloning https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT to /private/var/folders/9v/78_d3w_973z7srt5r58tg5f40000gn/T/pip-req-build-m85h_k9v
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT /private/var/folders/9v/78_d3w_973z7srt5r58tg5f40000gn/T/pip-req-build-m85h_k9v
  Resolved https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT to commit b529efc7e792eefbb468a119ef704783e70250e8
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pytest (from torchTT==2.0)
  Using cached pytest-7.4.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18 in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torchTT==2.0) (1.26.3)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.7 in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torchTT==2.0) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opt_einsum in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torchTT==2.0) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (2023.12.2)
Collecting iniconfig (from pytest->torchTT==2.0)
  Using cached iniconfig-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pytest->torchTT==2.0) (23.1)
Collecting pluggy<2.0,>=0.12 (from pytest->torchTT==2.0)
  Using cached pluggy-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from jinja2->torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from sympy->torch>=1.7->torchTT==2.0) (1.3.0)
Using cached pytest-7.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (325 kB)
Using cached pluggy-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: torchTT
  Building wheel for torchTT (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [157 lines of output]
      
      
        _                 _   _____ _____
       | |_ ___  _ __ ___| |_|_   _|_   _|
       | __/ _ \| '__/ __| '_ \| |   | |
       | || (_) | | | (__| | | | |   | |
        \__\___/|_|  \___|_| |_|_|   |_|
      
      
      
      running bdist_wheel
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:502: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using the slow distutils backend.
        warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_amen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/manifold.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_division.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/nn.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_aux_ops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_torchtt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_tt_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_decomposition.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/solvers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/cpp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_iterative_solvers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/interpolate.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/grad.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_dmrg.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      copying torchtt/_extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/torchtt
      running build_ext
      building 'torchttcpp' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/cpp
      clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/include -I/Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include -I/Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/include/python3.11 -c cpp/cpp_ext.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/cpp/cpp_ext.o -lblas -llapack -std=c++14 -Wno-c++11-narrowing -g -w -O3 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_clang\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1002\" -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=torchttcpp -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4:2: error: C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use PyTorch.
      #error C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use PyTorch.
       ^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:6:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/cpp_hook.h:2:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/function_hook.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/Tensor.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:11:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/c10/core/Device.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/c10/util/Exception.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/c10/util/StringUtil.h:6:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/c10/util/string_view.h:4:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/c10/util/C++17.h:27:2: error: You need C++17 to compile PyTorch
      #error You need C++17 to compile PyTorch
       ^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:11:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/NamedTensorUtils.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/TensorNames.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/WrapDimUtils.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/IListRef.h:632:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/IListRef_inl.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/List.h:490:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/List_inl.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/ivalue.h:1499:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h:1061:30: error: no template named 'is_convertible_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_convertible'?
              if constexpr (::std::is_convertible_v<typename c10::invoke_result_t<T &&, Future&>, IValueWithStorages>) {
                            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                   is_convertible
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_convertible.h:29:61: note: 'is_convertible' declared here
      template <class _T1, class _T2> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_convertible
                                                                  ^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:11:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/NamedTensorUtils.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/TensorNames.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/WrapDimUtils.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/IListRef.h:632:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/IListRef_inl.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/List.h:490:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/List_inl.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/ivalue.h:1499:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h:1061:112: error: expected unqualified-id
              if constexpr (::std::is_convertible_v<typename c10::invoke_result_t<T &&, Future&>, IValueWithStorages>) {
                                                                                                                     ^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd_not_implemented_fallback.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/library.h:68:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/op_registration/op_registration.h:11:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/KernelFunction.h:251:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/KernelFunction_impl.h:1:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/impl/boxing.h:229:25: error: no template named 'is_same_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_same'?
          if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<void, Result>) {
                         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
                              is_same
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_same.h:22:29: note: 'is_same' declared here
      struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same : _BoolConstant<__is_same(_Tp, _Up)> { };
                                  ^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd_not_implemented_fallback.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/library.h:68:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/op_registration/op_registration.h:11:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/KernelFunction.h:251:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/KernelFunction_impl.h:1:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/boxing/impl/boxing.h:229:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
          if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<void, Result>) {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
      In file included from cpp/cpp_ext.cpp:1:
      In file included from cpp/full.h:1:
      In file included from cpp/define.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:9:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4:
      In file included from /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3:
      /Users/john/.conda/envs/Desktop/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:4:2: error: C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use ATen.
      #error C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use ATen.
       ^
      7 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torchTT
  Running setup.py clean for torchTT
Failed to build torchTT
ERROR: Could not build wheels for torchTT, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am quite confused. Since I have enabled c++17 in

```
std=c++17
```

Why it shows that

```
#error C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use ATen.
```

and

```
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

The following is the link for the torchTT package.

> https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT

It has several requirements and I have checked that I have already satisfied. It has two versions on installations, either via pip or manually via git clone. It constantly shows the error message that I need c++17 to compile PyTorch.

How to resolve that along with pip command?

Comment: Where from have you got the idea to pass `std=c++17` as environment variable? Currently the command line includes `-std=c++14` so this doesn't work.

Comment: May I ask how to fix it in the command line with pip?

Comment: Try `CFLAGS="-std=c++17" pip install git+https://github.com/ion-g-ion/torchTT`